# Codeigniter doesn't show Images

Tags: image, codeigniter

I have a problem with CodeIgniter showing images in the function `detail`. In the function `index`, they are shown. Can someone show me where the problem is?

```
class Reference extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('reference_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['work'] = $this->reference_model->getList();
        $menu['page'] = "Reference";
        $menu['pages'] = $this->pages->getPages();

        $this->basic_template->set('title','Reference | DSVision');
        $this->basic_template->menu('menu_view',$menu);
        $this->basic_template->script('reference_script_view');
        $this->basic_template->view('basic_script', 'reference_view',$data);
    }

    public function detail($number)
    {
        if($this->reference_model->exist($number) == 0)
            redirect('reference');

        $data['id'] = $number;
        $data['work'] = $this->reference_model->getWork($number);
        $menu['page'] = "Reference";
        $menu['pages'] = $this->pages->getPages();

        $this->basic_template->set('title','Reference | DSVision');
        $this->basic_template->menu('menu_view',$menu);
        $this->basic_template->view('basic', 'detail_view',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post any of the view code? :)

Comment: So which variable would be your image (path)?

Comment: Image path is right but in function 'detail' it doesn't show.

Comment: We need to see your view code.

Comment: ye mostlikely the view file has the wrong path. Try setting your images like this `<img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/photo.png')?>">`. Note you must load the URL Helper

Comment: @Daniel: can you show me your view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs when you give the image src as `src="/images/logo.png"`.

When giving a path, do it like this:

```
src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>/image/logo.png"
```

Take note that you must set the **base_url** in **config.php** inside the **config** folder.

This problem occured because the browser is trying to find the image directory inside your controller directory as if you are loading a function!

Comment: You have a true. I use `base_url()` and it is `localhost/dsvision/`. When I check url of image in function `index`, url is `http://localhost/dsvision/assets/images/logo.png`, but in function `detail` is url `http://localhost/dsvision/reference/detail/assets/images/logo.png` and a code is `<a href="dsvision"><img src="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/logo.png"); ?>" alt="Logo - DSVision" width="150px" height="80px"></a>`. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Dear Friend, try this:

`<a href="dsvision"><img src="<?php echo $this->config->item('base_url'); ?>assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo - DSVision" width="150px" height="80px"></a>`

if your base url is: `http://localhost/dsvision/`

Comment: >I dont think so it is possible. Please check your config.php in details.  
>It should be like:  
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/dsvision/';  
$config['base_path'] = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dsvision\\";`  
and .htaccess like  
`RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /archiclub.com/index.php/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

u have to put every images, js etc. in your root-dir of CI. Example:

```
 /yourapp/css/style.css
```

In your view you write e.g. the following:

```
 <link type="text/javascript" src="<? echo base_url() ?>css/style.css" />
```